# Yii2 UrlManager Breaks On Periods

Tags: yii2

I am currently using yii2 `urlManager` to create a pretty URL.  It receives a parameter and then looks up users based on it. Unfortunately, if the parameter contains a period, it won't run at all and redirects to a `404` page.

So,

```
mysite.com/me/jbroad
```

works perfectly, but

```
mysite.com/me/j.broad
```

returns a 404 page.

Here is my url manager code

```
'urlManager' => [
     'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'rules' => [
         '' => 'site/index',
         'me/<id:\w+>' => 'kit/page',
         'generate/<id:\w+>' => 'kit/generate',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
     ],
],
```

Comment: do mark the answer if it worked for you

Comment: Yes, this worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You are using the regex with token `\w+` which matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and does not include a period or `.`.

so change it to `[\w\.]+` and your rule will now be

```
me/<id:[\w\.]+>' => 'kit/page',
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of \w+ , put [-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+

**example:**

```
    'me/<id:[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+>' => 'kit/page',
```

Comment: `\w` is a token that represents `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` you just need to add a `\.` in the character class like `[\w\.]+` and that is it

Comment: ok. "\w" A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character. Thanks

Comment: Also, I was typing and I did not see your answer/ So I gave your answer 'Upvote'

Comment: its ok, it happens a lot with everyone, appreciate the upvote.