# Form not submitting in Yii 2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

When i clicked my submit button in form it won't happen anything. im try to fill the form and submit but it wont submit. actually it doesn't happen anything. Yii 2.0

This is my userForm View.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;     
$this->title = 'User Form';
?>   
<?php 
    if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')) {
        # code...
        echo Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success');
    }
?>

<!-- to start the form -->
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<!-- text fields -->
<?= $form->field($model,'name'); ?>
<?= $form->field($model,'email'); ?>

<!-- button -->
<?= Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']); ?>
```

This my actionUser Controller in siteController.php.

```
public function actionUser()
    {
        $model = new UserForm;

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
            //set flash data
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','Successfully entered !..');
        }

        return $this->render('userForm',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

This is my UserForm model.

```
<?php 

namespace app\models; 

use yii\base\Model;


class UserForm extends Model
{
    public $name;
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name','email'],'required'],
            ['email','email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console ? and does it run the frontend validation when you type in the inputs?

Comment: Is it possible that it's because you don't have `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>` closing the form?

Comment: @Bizley that should have been added as an answer, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when you have missing `ActiveForm::end()` call:

Add this at the end of your form:

```
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Although you can post a valuable comment as an answer but you should wait for a bit before doing that, sometimes people are not sure if they are correct or not due to not being near their computer to test the solution, so they add a comment which the OP can verify and they can post it as an answer later, in this case it looks odd, or like stealing others credit, hope you understand. Between that is not a valid code you have posted , there is extra spacing

Comment: About the post or comment, let the management decide on this. This is your opinion.  
I congratulate Bizley. Because it does not judge quickly.
 Looking at the timeline, everyone will find out I was typing and Bizley commented. (3-minute difference). When I opened the page, Bizley was not a comment and when typing me So no longer judge quickly.

Comment: Not judging you otherwise i could have mentioned it [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522404/yii2-urlmanager-breaks-on-periods/55522623#55522623) too. you could have just said that i was posting when bizley commented, but you started judging **ME**.

Comment: Dear friend Aslam I have many reasons for your ambiguity, But can not on 124 characters....Copy from translator and editor and .... Also, I upvote Bizley, to thank.
With respect.